# Predicate function to test if file is under version control?

Tags: git, version-control

What is the predicate function to determine if a given file is under version control?  (I'm using git.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The canonical way is to call `(vc-backend <file>)`, AFAIK.

Answer (score 2):

Try `(vc-git-responsible-p (buffer-file-name))`.

Comment: Thanks, that's 95% of the way there.  The main hold-up is that it will incorrectly declare a file under version control if it is in a VC'd directory, even if the file itself is supposed to be ignored by VC.  It's enough for my limited purposes, but let me leave the post open a bit longer to see if anyone can figure out the last little bit.

Comment: @Dan, follow up with `vc-state`

Comment: I *think* that does it, although the docstring suggests that `vc-state` could return `nil`, `ignored`, or `unregistered` for a non-VC'd file.  Could you add the `vc-state` part to your answer?  (By the way, that looks to be the VC system-agnostic answer.)

Answer (score 1):

`vc-registered` is correct. You just pass it the file path and it will work with any backend. Use `vc-responsible-backend` to get the backend name.

```el
(vc-registered (buffer-file-name))
;; => t

(vc-responsible-backend (buffer-file-name))
;; => Git
```

Comment: Precision from `vc-responsible-backend` docstring: "If FILE is already registered, return the
backend of FILE.  If FILE is not registered, then the
first backend in `vc-handled-backends' that declares itself
responsible for FILE is returned."

Answer (score -1):

These answers are wrong.

You should use (vc-git-registered (file)). Returns t or nil.

(vc-state (file)) returns state of repository. Not a state of a single file.
vc-state returns 'up-to-date on file which is not under version control but it's located in directory which us under control of GIT.

Comment: `vc-git-registered` seems indeed a good choice if the VC is git, but how is using `vc-backend` wrong? What you say about `vc-state` is not what the docstring says, nor what the quick tests I did show.

Comment: It's because vc-backend gives false results on GIT. It cannot see a difference between files added/staged to git but not commited.  vc-backend returns nil on file which is staged already.

Comment: After tesing again, on emacs 24.4.1 both `vc-state` and `vc-backend` do recognize staged files.